# How do I capture a substring of a variable generated inside a loop and pass it to the following task?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have the following scenario:

[image]

I'm looping through files in a directory.

For each file, I have to capture part of the file name and I have to use it as a parameter on the "Update Exceptions" task.

How do I save part of the file name (which the loop is looping through) and then pass it as a parameter for the stored procedure in "Update Exceptions?"

I already have the function to extract the string from the file name, I just need to know where to put it.

Again, I want to grab string X from the file name that the loop is at and then pass this variable to the stored procedure in the "Update Exceptions" task.

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable of type Object. Mind the (container) scope of the variable.
[image: Variables panel in Visual Studio]

Map the output of a task to the variable.
[image: Properties window of an SQL task]

Use it in your ForEach loop.
[image: Properties windows of a Foreach loop task]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

1. Create two `String` variables called `CurrentFile` and `CurrentFileSubstring`
2. In your FELC task, map `User::CurrentFile` to 0
   [image: FELC mapping]
3. Create a Script Task between Move File to Processed Folder and Update Exceptions
4. Give your Script Task Read access to `CurrentFile` and ReadWrite access to `CurrentFileSubstring`
   [image: Var access]
5. Put your function into the Script Task code.  Read the value from `CurrentFile` and write the substring value from your function to `CurrentFileSubstring`.
   `Dts.Variables[User::CurrentFileSubstring].Value = MySubstringFunction(CurrentFile);`
6. Your Update Exceptions task can now use the `CurrentFileSubstring` value.

[For more information on looping over files, see this link](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx)